# Spring 3 -- how to do a GET request from a forward

Tags: spring-mvc, http-status-code-405

I'm trying to forward a request to another Spring controller that takes a GET request, but it's telling me POST is not supported.  Here is the relevant portion from my first controller method, which does take a POST request, since I'm using it for a login function.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(@ModelAttribute("administrator") Administrator administrator,
    Model model) {
    // code that's not germane to this problem
    return "forward:waitingBulletins";
}
```

Here is the method I'm trying to forward to.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/waitingBulletins", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getWaitingBulletins(Model model) {
        // the actual code follows
    }
```

Here is the error message in my browser.

```
HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message Request method 'POST' not supported

description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource (Request method 'POST' not supported).
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`forward` maintains the original request intact, so you are forwarding a `POST` request and missing a handler for it.

By the looks of it, what you're really trying to implement is the [POST-redirect-GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern, which uses redirect instead of forward.

You only need to change your `POST` handler to:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public String login(@ModelAttribute("administrator") Administrator administrator,
    Model model) {
    // code that's not germane to this problem
    return "redirect:waitingBulletins";
}
```

to make it work.